# Spring: Can't map YAML to list of objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yaml file with errors and error messages. I'm attempting to load them into a class, `RefreshErrors` within a common jar used by my Spring Boot microservices. The common jar does have Spring Boot on the classpath, but there is no `SpringBootApplication` - it's simply included by other applications. So that may be why I'm not getting any values in `RefreshErrors`?

Here's the yaml, which is in `application.yml`, located under `src/main/resources`:

```
refreshErrorsProperties:
  refreshErrors:
    -
      recordStatus: "Error"
      errorCode: "502 Bad Gateway"
      errorMessage: "AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified. Please try refreshing again after the service becomes available."
    -
      recordStatus: "Error"
      errorCode: "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"
      errorMessage: "AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified. Please try refreshing again after the service becomes available."
    -
...
```

And here's my configuration for the class I want the yaml mapped to:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="refreshErrors")
public class RefreshErrorsProperties {
    private List<RefreshErrors> refreshErrors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The `RefreshErrors` class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RefreshErrors {
    private String errorCode;
    private String recordStatus;
    private String errorMessage;
}
```

I autowire `RefreshErrors` in another class (see below) and I do get an object reference, but all the values inside (like `errorCode` etc) are empty. Any help would be appreciated!

```
@Autowired
public void setRefreshErrorsProperties(RefreshErrorsProperties refreshErrorsProperties) {
    RefreshJobDetailHelper.refreshErrorsProperties = refreshErrorsProperties;
}
...
    RefreshErrors error;
    if (exception != null) {
        String fullException = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception);
        error = refreshErrorsProperties.getRefreshErrors().stream()
                .filter(f -> fullException.contains(f.getErrorCode()))
                .findAny()
                .orElseGet((Supplier<? extends RefreshErrors>) new RefreshErrors("Error", ERROR.getValue(), "An error has occurred while refreshing this record. ESS has been notified. Please try refreshing again after the issue has been resolved."));
    } else {
       error =  new RefreshErrors("No data", ERROR_NO_DATA.getValue(), "Data is not available in the source for this product, domain, and effective date.");
    }
```

Comment: can you try registering your class in @EnableConfigurationProperties(RefreshErrors.class) and see if it works? and also change to @Configuration from Component

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the prefix `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "refreshErrors")`. It should be like `@ConfigurationProperties`, with no prefix, the prefix is required when you need to map properties under the prefix, but refreshErrors is the property you want to map and not the prefix. The below code works fine.
I have refactored a bit :

**properties file:**

```
    refresh-errors:
      -
        record-status: "Error"
        error-code: "502 Bad Gateway"
        error-message: "AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified. Please try refreshing again after the service becomes available."
      -
        record-status: "Error"
        error-code: "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"
        error-message: "AWS service is tempoarily not available. ESS has been notified. Please try refreshing again after the service becomes available."
```

**PropertiesMapperClass :**

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class RefreshErrorsProperties {
    private List<RefreshErrors> refreshErrors = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    public static class RefreshErrors {
        private String errorCode;
        private String recordStatus;
        private String errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Monit Singh, I just tried your class, and I get an error that says "prefix must be specified". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oddly, while Intellij reports that error, the class compiles anyway.

Comment: I need to be able to instantiate `RefreshErrors`,

Comment: That's strange because it works fine for me, even from the documentation it says, default prefix value is blank. Are you sure there is no typo because it says invalid class field? Otherwise, you can try defining a prefix, like 
errors.refresh-errors: 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="errors")

Comment: Thanks Mohit, I did exactly as you suggest and added another prefix. I’m still struggling, I’ll update my question to show what I have now.

Comment: Yes, please, then I can try to reproduce.

Comment: I've updated my code! i really appreciate you help, @Mohit.

Comment: by seeing you files you should change this @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="refreshErrorsProperties")
because prefix is the property just before other properties you are trying map.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't change your annotation,the yaml file node refreshErrors's attribute should not be a list,
the yaml file should be

```
refresh-errors:
  record-status: "Error"
  error-code: "502 Bad Gateway"
  error-message: "AWS service ..."
```

which may not be what you want,
if you don't change your yaml file,
the code should be like Mohit Singh shows